# submitting arrays to php via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am having issues figuring out how to submit a form via ajax that has items with the same name(this form is dynamically created and has to use the same names for some fields).

This is the JS code that I have

```
<script>
  var toggle123 = function() {
      var chair = document.getElementsByName('chair[]');
    var item1 = document.getElementsByName('item[]');
    var price = document.getElementsByName('price[]');
    var table  = document.getElementById('table');

    // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
        var dataString = 'table='+table+'';

    for(i=0;i<item1.length;i++)
{
      dataString += + '& item1[]' + '=' + item1[i];

}
for(i=0;i<chair.length;i++)
{
      dataString += + '& chair[]' + '=' + chair[i];

}
for(i=0;i<price.length;i++)
{
      dataString += + '& price[]' + '=' + price[i];

}

        if (chair == '' || item1 == '') {
        } 
        else {
                    // AJAX code to submit form.
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "submit.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html) {
                    alert(html);
                    }
                    });
                }
        return false;

  var mydiv = document.getElementById('table1');
  if (mydiv.style.display === 'block' || mydiv.style.display === '')
    mydiv.style.display = 'none';
  else
    mydiv.style.display = 'block'
  }
  </script>
```

I want it to submit to submit.php and also to hide the div that is open (table1). 
I can get it to go to submit.php but I am not sure if the data is actually getting sent there or if it is just blank.  It tells me there was an invalid argument for the foreach loop in submit.php.

Here is submit.php

```
<?php
include('dbconfig.php');
// Fetching Values From the post method
$table = $_POST['table_id'];
foreach($_POST["item1"] AS $key => $val) {
$chair = $val;
$price = $_POST['price'][$key];
$chair = $_POST['chair'][$key];

$query = mysqli_query($dbconfig,"insert into orders(table_id, price, item, chair) values ('$table', '$price', '$item', '$chair')"); //Insert Query
echo "Form Submitted succesfully";
}
?>
```

This is the javascript for the dynamic form....each time a button is clicked, this adds onto the form:

```
listholder.innerHTML += "Chair "+row.chair+"-<input type='hidden' id='chair' name='chair[]' value='"+row.chair+"' /><input type='hidden' id='table' name='table' value='"+row.table_id+"' /><input type='hidden' id='item' name='item[]' value='"+row.item1+"' /><input type='hidden' id='price' name='price[]' value='"+row.item1+"' />" + row.item1 + " - " + row.chair + " (<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='deleteCar(" + row.id + ");'>Delete Car</a>)<br>";
```

I think my main issue is probably forming the datastring that gets passed to submit.php.  If anyone could help me figure this out, that would be great!

(P.S. toggle123 is activated via a button click (that works fine)

Comment: You can collect the data in array format and then send it to the php

Comment: Much simpler to use jQuery `serialize()` to collect all the form data to send ... `var formData =$('#formID').serialize()` ...would replace all your loops

Comment: @charlietfl, How would that work though?  I need to submit it as an array to php with the array hints at the end ([]) for it.  Since name doesn't need to be unique, that is why I am using it.  using the ID of the form element wont work....or am I misunderstanding

Comment: `serialize()` will create that array. Not sure why form ID won't work to target the form element. As for receiving the data try `echo json_encode($_POST); exit;` at very beginning of file. Then look inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network and you can see exactly what gets returned ... or switch out `alert(html);` for `console.log(html)`

Comment: @charlietfl My understanding is that form id needs to be unique.  I have no way of making a unique id as the elements are added on anytime a button is clicked.  I need multiple items with name[] to submit to php.  Im sorry if this is confusing or I am misunderstanding, I am new to JS/jquery

Comment: Your `<form>` is most likely unique is it not? The inputs are being dynamically added inside that single tag. If not can still bind a handler to a class of forms and do same thing

Comment: OK, I think I see what you are saying.  How exactly does serialize format it for submission to PHP?  This is all with one page (no refresh) so I don't think the echo piece to view stuff would work, would it?